# Gorm finder with dynamic argument?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I am using a GORM finder but I am getting a runtime error and I think that is because my syntax is incorrect. Here is the line of code I have problems with:

```
def accountsOwnedByUser = AccountRecord.findAllWhere(owners.contains(indivRecord.uniqueId))
```

where owners is a List property of the AccountRecord class. I want to find all the owners of a given account and I'm doing it by searching for individuals whose unique id appears in the account's ownership list. But currently I get this error:

```
No such property: owners for class: com.twc.fatcaone.FileImportService. Stacktrace follows:
Message: No such property: owners for class: com.twc.fatcaone.FileImportService
    Line | Method
->>  968 | doCall                         in com.twc.fatcaone.FileImportService$_$tt__deleteIndividualRecord_closure18
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|    967 | $tt__deleteIndividualRecord    in com.twc.fatcaone.FileImportService$$EOkgHOSW
|    168 | doCall . . . . . . . . . . . . in com.twc.fatcaone.FileImportService$_$tt__excelIndividualFileUpload_closure16$$EOkgHOSW
|    162 | $tt__excelIndividualFileUpload in com.twc.fatcaone.FileImportService$$EOkgHOSW
|    147 | upload . . . . . . . . . . . . in com.twc.fatcaone.CustomerController
|    198 | doFilter                       in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|     63 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . . in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|   1145 | runWorker                      in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run                            in java.lang.Thread
```

I need something like `it.owners` or an equivalent thereof that can be used as an arguments to GORM's dynamic finder. Is there an equivalent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?...

```
def idToSearchFor = indivRecord.uniqueId
AccountRecord.where {
    idToSearchFor in owners    
}.list()
```

I can't tell for sure without seeing your model but something like that may help.

Comment: Will this give me a List of AccountRecord objects such that their owners (List) property, contains the indivRecord's unique id? If so, I think this is exactly what I need.